# One web application project's aspx file is not working into another web application project

Tags: asp.net, web

I have a webapplcation name HRM. Now i am trying to add a file aspx with another project name HRM1 (also web applicaitonFile), but i am getting this error as i try to see that file in browser: **Pareser ERROR.

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. Message: Could not load type 'HRM1.WebForm10'.
*Line 1: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Nationality.aspx.cs" Inherits="HRM1.WebForm10" %>***

I also have try inherits= "HRM1.WebForm10", but the same parser error ocurring i dont know why? I am using VS 12 and webapplication.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HRM1.App_Code.BLL;
namespace HRM
{
    public partial class WebForm10 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        clsNationality objNationality = new clsNationality();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
             //   BindNationality();
            }
        }
        protected void BindNationality()
        {
            gvNationality.DataSource = objNationality.SelectAll();
            gvNationality.DataBind();
        }
        protected void btn_Ins_Nation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objNationality.Name = txtNationalityName.Text;
            int a = objNationality.Insert();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                lblOutPut.Text = "Successfully Insert";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutPut.Text = "Error";
            }
        }

        protected void btn_update_Nation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objNationality.User_ID = 1;
            objNationality.Nation_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RecordNo"]);
            objNationality.Name = txtNationalityName.Text;
           int b= objNationality.Update();
            BindNationality();

            if (b > 0)
            {
                BindNationality();
                lblOutPut.Text = "Successfully Updated";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutPut.Text = "Error";
            }
        }

        protected void btn_dlt_Nation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            objNationality.Name = txtNationalityName.Text;

            int c = objNationality.Delete();

            if (c > 0)
            {

                lblOutPut.Text = "Successfully Deleted";
                BindNationality();
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutPut.Text = "Delete Error";
            }
        }

        protected void gvNationality_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.ToString().ToUpper() == "EDIT")
            {
                ViewState["RecordNo"] = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                objNationality.Nation_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RecordNo"]);
                objNationality.SelectByID();
                txtNationalityName.Text = objNationality.Name;

            }
        }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you build the app itself ? Also try right-click on Nationality.aspx.cs -> properties -> does the target say "Compile" ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the master page "~/Site.Master" exist in the target project ?
Did you well imported the .apsx, .aspx.vb and .aspx.designer.vb files ?

Comment: May be because in your code the namespace is still HRM

Comment: my current project name HRM that i change it to HRM

Comment: but in the Page directive you still have `Inherits="HRM1.WebForm10"` think you must change HRM1 to HRM