# How to add Website project's aspx page into Webapplication Project in VS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, web

it really easy to add a exsisting aspx file or any kind of other thing into website(VS)
simply we need to copy paste that file into website folde as msdn suggested

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hds5k93(v=vs.100).aspx

but how to add an aspx file into `webapplication` project cause `webapplication` is different from website.

For information about the difference between Web site projects and Web application projects, see Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects.

my question is how to add an aspx file into web application i am doing copy paste into my folder but getting error i have asked before see blow link.

[One web application project's aspx file is not working into another web application project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783900/one-web-application-projects-aspx-file-is-not-working-into-another-web-applicat)

Answer (score 0):

Copy your existing aspx file and paste it directly to your new web application where you want to add it. Now open this web application Visual Studio and in solution explorer click the button "show all files". Once this added file shown up in visual studio right click this page and select "Include in Project". Hope this will work.